# encoding/xml handle unmapped elements

Tags: go

From http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal

> - If the XML element contains a sub-element that hasn't matched any of the above rules and the struct has a field with tag ",any",
>     unmarshal maps the sub-element to that struct field.

I'm having trouble getting the remainder of an XML envelope into my struct (to show that I have an incomplete mapping)

http://play.golang.org/p/mnFqAcguJQ

I know you can use exactly this method with bson.M from the mgo packages using ,inline - but it looks like map[string]interface{} isn't the answer here.

EDIT:
After some additional playing, I've found what I believe to be some additional unexpected behavior.

Switching to []string as a type starts to accept input, but no key/value pairs: http://play.golang.org/p/wCAJeeQa4m

I also planned on adapting encode/xml in order to parse html. I do not see in the documentation that if an element exists more than once, it will save the last instance of it, rather than erroring out: http://play.golang.org/p/0MY__R-Xi3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here: http://play.golang.org/p/iY8YlxYym0

Since `c` is something concrete, it shouldn't use `",any"`, hence it should have a struct definition. `C` itself contains a list of arbitrary tags, hence it should contain an `[]Tag xml:'",any"'`... now to capture the `Tag` itself, you need xml.Name to get the tag name and something with ",innerxml".

Finally the result is this:

```
const xmlString = `<foo><a>1</a><b>2</b><c><c1>3</c1><c2>4</c2></c></foo>`
type Foo struct {
    A int   `xml:"a"`
    B int   `xml:"b"`
    C Extra `xml:"c"`
}

type Extra struct {
    Items []Tag `xml:",any"`
}

type Tag struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Content string `xml:",innerxml"`
}
```

Or the shorter version:

```
type Foo struct {
    A int   `xml:"a"`
    B int   `xml:"b"`
    C struct {
        Items []struct {
            XMLName xml.Name
            Content string `xml:",innerxml"`
        } `xml:",any"`
    } `xml:"c"`
}
```

For HTML there is [go.net/html](http://code.google.com/p/go.net/html). Using xml parser for html will be complicated.

Comment: Thanks. You can also capture all the attributes using https://stackoverflow.com/a/49950640/332798