# xml Unmarshal innerXml and its attributes

Tags: go

I want to Unmarshal the innerXml and its attributes. I write a Unmarshal function to implement this, but it looks like the function is in an infinite loop. The error information is

```
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit 
fatal error: stack overflow
```

The example is [here](http://play.golang.org/p/8uAG7plKDy).

I don't know why this happens. Could someone help me, thanks.

Update1: Thanks Ainar-G. I tried his example. It works as get the innerXml as chardata which I did't find. If I change the example as [this](http://play.golang.org/p/25qsRtfU0U), the result is empty, it should include all the raw xml in .

Update2: I find a solution, but may be a little wordy. [code](http://play.golang.org/p/ONKlk9B07a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `UnmarshalXML` method you call `xml.(*Decoder).DecodeElement`, which in turn calls `UnmarshalXML`, etc. This creates the infinite loop. Either create a wrapper struct, or unmarshal only a part of your struct in your `UnmarshalXML`.

**EDIT:** if you want to unmarshal all attributes of a node, see the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25534187/1892060).

Working example:

```
func (in *innerXml) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    in.XMLName = start.Name
    in.Attrs = make(map[string]string)
    for _, attr := range start.Attr {
        in.Attrs[attr.Name.Local] = attr.Value
    }

    err := d.DecodeElement(&in.Value, &start)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/TLcqFSyn94

Comment: Thanks for your help. Except the attributes, I also want the innerxml.  Just like the example.

Comment: @Hugh if this is answering your question, you should [mark the answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.